# Open Windows 7 help (helpPane.exe) from .Net application

Tags: c#

I am trying to open windows 7 help from a .Net form application to a specific bookmark, at printer installation for example.

I tried to open it in the same whay that I open Control Panel applets (Back & Restore in the example below).

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\control.exe", "/name Microsoft.BackupAndRestore");

startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But it doesn't work.
I didn't succeed neither to open the .exe.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you get an error or exception? If so what was it? That would help.

Comment: No exception. Just nothing happens, neither a process of help is starting.

Comment: Interesting. So no process is created? What are you getting back from `Process.Start`? Anything? If the app you're starting is failing silently after creation it might have written something to the event log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC `HelpPane.exe` works with `.h1s` files so if you have full path to such a file you can just use for example [`Process.Start (@"C:\myDir\myhelpfile.h1s");`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) to open it.

According to MS another option (most likely the recommenced one) is to host the HelpPane (which is basically a COM object!) - for details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms728715%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Other important MSDN links are:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757030.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms728718%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms728713%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

From the above links:

> The Help Pane API can only be used to display the Windows Help content
>   set. It can be customized by OEMs, system builders, and enterprise
>   customers under license agreement, but cannot be used by third-party
>   programs. Displaying content that is not part of the Windows Help
>   content set is not supported.

*Depending on what you want to achieve you might need to first sign a license agreement with MS...*

EDIT - as per comments:

To display a specific topic you need to call the method [`DisplayTask` of the COM object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms728704%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)  with the URL of that topic.

**EDIT 2 - as per comments the final solution:**

Add a reference to `C:\Windows\System32\HelpPaneProxy.dll` to the project then you can use the HelpPane like this

```
HxHelpPane pHelpPane = new HxHelpPane(); 
pHelpPane.DisplayTask("mshelp://windows/?id=e725b43f-94e4-4410-98e7-cc87ab2739aa");
```

Comment: I got the following exception :
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception was unhandled
  Message=The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I actually want to open windows help on a specific chapter, like Printers intallation, after searching I found that helpPane is used for help presentation to windows 7. That's why I try to open this API, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @annavk follow the links above... for displaying specific topics you need to know "URL" of the topic see esp. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms728704%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: That's correct. Thanks @Yahia
I add a reference C:\Windows\System32\HelpPaneProxy.dll to my project and then with the code bellow the help opened.

`HxHelpPane pHelpPane = new HxHelpPane();
            pHelpPane.DisplayTask("mshelp://windows/?id=e725b43f-94e4-4410-98e7-cc87ab2739aa");`

Comment: @annavk glad that I was of help :-) please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was usefeull.