# Develop a User Guide help that can be opened from the Windows Application

Tags: winforms, documentation

I've almost completed a Windows Application (Windows Forms) project for a client, but one of his requests is to have the typical "?" menu item that opens an help file with a User Guide help.

I know how to build documentation based on Documentation Xml (and I did that already), but this is something different: it must be a User Guide, something that the end-user will understand (he doesn't care to know anything about the code behind the application), with screenshots, HOPW-TOs, FAQ, etc.

User must be able to always open it (so, a web site or anything that requires an internet connection is not an option).

I was thinking to use an actual help file (msha + mshc files?), but since I only know how to build it from Documentation Xml, I have no idea of how I can create it and how I can make it shows from the Windows Application.

Any hint?

Comment: Are you trying to create a dynamic document? If not, try convert your xml documentation to pdf format, and open it when user click `?` button

Comment: You need to sit down and write a user guide, which has absolutelu nothing to do with Documentation Xml, then save it as a standard document type that everyone can open. This is pretty much HTML OR PDF nowadays.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear that I'm aware this has nothing to do with Documentation Xml: I've actually mentioned it to clarify that this is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a windows help file with this: http://download.microsoft.com/download/office97dev/helpws97/4.03/win98/en-us/hcwsetup.exe

This is a help file creator application.

Comment: What is it? Please, don't just send me a link to a download file, but at least a link to a page that explains what this file is/does.

Comment: Sorry, i never had a details page, but i updated the answer.

Comment: since you knew what the application was, a quick search would have helped you to complete your answer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21138

I'll accept your answer, as this is the official tool from Microsoft, but it lacks details.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a .chm/help file that can integrate itself in your application from XML mark-up embedded in code (or otherwise) is never going to be a straight forward matter of conversion. I would suggest looking into the following tools (although they are not free, there may be alternative free tools available):

1. [Doc-to-Help](http://www.doctohelp.com/?gclid=CJzM2MnSsLYCFcjKtAodXVQAKg) We use this and it can convert a Word document directly into a .chm help file.
2. [Help+Manual](http://www.helpandmanual.com/)
3. [HelpSmith](http://www.helpsmith.com/)

In addition take a look at this question

[What tools are available to create a help file in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3077361/626442)

It has some very useful answers and may provide exactly what you are looking for.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it *yet*, but [HelpPane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms728713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be what you're looking for. It's the replacement for CHM as of Windows Vista.

One thought would be to build a self-hosted ASP.NET site, so that you can use Master Pages for your consistent look-and-feel, and then point a HelpPane instance to that site.

With a little bit of digging I'm sure you'll be able to find a suitable library for self-hosting an ASP.NET site.

EDIT1: Also see this [SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041116/open-windows-7-help-helppane-exe-from-net-application).

EDIT2: It seems that HelpPane.exe will only display Windows help topics. Perhaps [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon.helppanecontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will be better suited for your needs. HTH